# Website is crashing on Safari in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, responsive-design, safari, ios9.3.2

We have a complicated problem on a website of a customer. The Website crashed on iOS 9.3.2 on iPhone 6 Plus. It does however not crash on the newest version of iOS or even on a iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3.1.

How to reproduce the error:

1. Open the website with iPhone 6 (or iPhone 6 Plus):
   http://www.kindervorhang.ch/Vorhaenge-fixfertig-Verdunkler-Ellie
2. Klick on «In den Warenkorb» to add the product to the basket
3. Now if you scroll the website or change the orientation it will crash
4. Now if you touch something or scroll a bit it will crash again until you see a full screen error description

Does anyone have a smiliar problem or now how to solve it?

I got this errorcode in Xcode:

```
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone diagnosticd[88] <Error>: unable to find offset 0x804cf98c in shared cache for arch 'arm64'
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone ReportCrash[703] <Notice>: platform_task_update_threads failed 1
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone ReportCrash[703] <Notice>: Formulating report for process[699] com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone assertiond[67] <Error>: assertion failed: 13F69: assertiond + 72572 [0B862A7D-6E8B-3778-AD17-C7694ECD5BCD]: 0x3
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone Unknown[67] <Error>: 
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone assertiond[67] <Error>: assertion failed: 13F69: assertiond + 72572 [0B862A7D-6E8B-3778-AD17-C7694ECD5BCD]: 0x3
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone Unknown[67] <Error>: 
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone UserEventAgent[26] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone ReportCrash[703] <Warning>: report not saved because it is non-actionable
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] <Error>: assertion failed: 13F69: launchd + 116796 [9F6284CF-8A17-36CC-9DB5-85D510A21F14]: 0x3
May 10 12:43:56 ASs-iPhone ReportCrash[704] <Warning>: Report of type '298(298)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tested the css line for line and found that everything was working if we commented this lines out:

```
div.set-65131>.colInside {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

div.set-53541 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute
}


div.set-53541>.colInside {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
}

div.set-53541>.colInside {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1240px;
  left: 0!important;
  right: 0!important;
  margin-left: auto!important;
  margin-right: auto!important;
  position: fixed
}
```

Now it is working across all different devices. The Problem is probably position fixed in combination width height 100%.

We found a different solution to apply our background-image.

Answer (score 3):

I just spent all day figuring out a similar issue. My website crashed on load on iPad 3 and iPhone 5. I finally narrowed it down to a CSS property:

```
#cv-section-header   {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It's hard to believe a CSS property could cause a website to break on older iOS, but it is what it is.